# Java Regex and PathMatcher

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing an application in Java that displays a list of files where the first word in the filename matches user defined string, then deletes or rearranges them depending on some preferences. I'm currently in the phase of finding a good way to find my files. Using [this Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) I ended up with something like this:

```
Path source = Paths.get(sourceText.getText());
Path dest = Paths.get(destText.getText());

System.out.println("Source:" + source.toString());
System.out.println("P/N: " + partNoText.getText());

String matchString = "glob:**" + partNoText.getText() + "*";

System.out.println("Matching: " + matchString);

fileFinder = new FileFinder(matchString);

try {
    Files.walkFileTree(source, fileFinder);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
for (Path path : fileFinder.getResult()) {
    System.out.println("Moving: " + path.getFileName());
    Path target = Paths.get(dest.toString() + "\\" + path.getFileName());

    try {
        Files.move(path, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where FileFinder extends SimpleFileVisitor and has this visitFile method:

```
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(file.toString());
    System.out.println(fileMatcher.matches(file));
    if (fileMatcher.matches(file)) {
        result.add(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

My issue with this is that the glob will pick up any file where the filename contains the part no. in any way. So if my file is called "12345 RevA Really Big Part 2: Electric Bugaloo" then the string would match if the user entered "1" or "123" or "Bugaloo". Ideally, it would only match if the user enterred "12345".

I tried switching my matchString to `"regex: .*" + partNoText + "\\b"`, which works in the regex test harness I modified from [this other Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html). What am I doing wrong? Does `PathMatcher` work differently than a regular `Matcher`?

P.S. Any variable that has the word "Text" in it, like `sourceText` and `partNoText` are JTextFields. Hopefull that is the only part of the code that is mostly unclear from what I clipped out of it.

Comment: Filename _globbing_ is _**not**_ a regular expression; globbing is much more limited than regex. Also, `foo*` as a glob matches foo-with-anything-after, the equivalent as a regex would be `foo.*` = foo followed by any single char `.` zero-or-more times `*`

Comment: _"Ideally, it would only match if the user enterred "12345"."_ Is part number _always_ the first part of the filename? Are all part numbers _exactly_ 5 digits? Is part number _always_ followed by a space?  Having a precise definition can help you find a good regex. I don't think globbing will do it in this case, although you could glob to reduce the match space and then regex match what globbing has found.

Comment: @StephenP For your first comment, it is my understanding that globbing and regex are both different ways one can create generalized strings to match against. You can see from the bottom part of my question that I decided to change from globbing to regex due to its limitations

Comment: @StephenP To you second comment; the part number is always first almost always with a space immediately following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Does PathMatcher work differently than a regular Matcher?"**
Yes. a `PathMatcher` works with filename *globbing*<sup>[1]</sup>, while a `Matcher` works with *regular expressions*.

See [What *Is* a Glob?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob) in the tutorial you linked, and compare that with the documentation for [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
Globbing is quite a bit more limited that regular expression matching.

If you have a strict file naming convention that is rigorously adhere to you probably can use globbing (I take back that last part of my previous comment).

Let's say your files are named as
`numeric part number` - `space` - `optional revision & space` - `description`

That is, the part number can have a variable number of digits, but the space after the part number is required and always present.

So your example *"12345 RevA Really Big Part 2: Electric Bugaloo"* fits that with partNum==12345, revision="RevA ", description="Really Big Part 2: Electric Bugaloo"

A user enters a part number `P/N: 123` as a variable `userPN` and you construct a glob as
`String glob = userPN + " *";` resulting in glob equalling `"123 *"`
This will *not* match 12345, as you desire, because of the space after the 3 will not match the 4.

If there is *not* a required space after the part number in the filename, but what follows is *always* alphabetic, either the Revision or the Description, you can construct a glob as
`String glob = userPN + "[A-Z,a-z]*";` giving glob = `123[A-Z,a-z]*` which also won't match 12345 because an alphabetic must follow the 123 and the 4 is not in that character range.

You can make your character range more complicated, say `[A-Z,a-z, ]` for an *optional* space, depending on your needs, **but** it all really comes down to your file naming convention.  You need to state that convention very precisely and adhere to it.

---

[1] a `PathMatcher` *can* use a regular expression instead of globbing if you specify the "syntax" as `regex` when calling [FileSystem.getPathMatcher(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)). This would be something like

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
PathMatcher pm = fs.getPathMatcher("regex:\\d{5}\\s.*");
```

Comment: If you read the first link I posted, right under the link that says "What is a glob?" is a line that states that regex can be used with PathMatchers. That's why I put "regex: ..." instead of "glob: ..." in my matching statement. However, it does seem like I've over-complicated this. Thank you for simplifying it for me.

Comment: @Eric - I saw that _"Glob syntax is easy to use and flexible but, if you prefer, you can also use regular expressions, or regex, syntax."_ but didn't see any way to do that. I've now found [getPathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) which is where you can specify `"regex:<some-pattern>"` as the _syntaxAndPattern_ argument. Knowing this could benefit future readers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you go on it very complicated way. Why would you use pat Marc her in the first place when you don't look for events.

Much easier it would be to walk through the file tree and for each directory iterate directory stream to match your glob.